# In Exchange Admin Center, from where the mobile data is generated, can we manipulate or append to that data?

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server, azure-powershell, domaincontroller

In Exchange Admin Center, from where the mobile data is generated, can we manipulate or append to that data?

any powershell command, script, any other language code or exe or anything, that can help manipulating or appending the data in Exchange Admin Center?

Comment: Does this ps cmdlet will help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mobiledevicemailboxpolicy?view=exchange-ps

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT , I have already added mobile policy.
I just want to have some data when i run this powershell script

`$UserList = Get-CASMailbox -Filter "HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq \`$true -and -not DisplayName -like 'CAS_{*'" | Get-Mailbox
$UserList | foreach {Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $_.Identity}`